# @foreach loop does not show anything

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to show all my orders from my orders table but nothing is showing up although I have registers in my table. 
Here is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = auth()->user()->orders;
    return view('pagini.my-orders')->with('orders', $orders);

}
```

Here is my @foreach

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
 {{$order->id}}
 {{presentPrice($order->billing_total)}}
     @foreach ($order->products as $product)
       {{$product->name}}
       <img src="{{asset($product->image)}}">
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Here is a picture of my orders table:
[Orders table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpj9F.png)
Here is the result I got:
[Result @foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AblGK.png)

Here are my models - User model:

```
public function orders(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Orders');
}
```

- Product model:

```
 public function orders(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders');
}
```

- Orders model:

  `public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
  public function products(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
  }`

Comment: can you show your model? is there any bug u find?

Comment: there is something in the variable if you do a `dd($orders);`?

Comment: auth()->user()->orders()->get(); you mean ?

Comment: I just thought about making a dd($orders) and it's showing me Collection {#616 ▼
  #items: []
} so it's empty but I don't get it why

Comment: still not working with auth()->user()->orders()->get(); gives me the same result

Comment: How do you define the relationship 'orders' in the users model? Is it possible that the user who's making the request has no related orders?

Comment: I posted my models in the questions @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Share output for `$orders = User::find(1)->orders;` ? if you are in tinker use `\App\User::find(1)->orders`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `orders` related to user use

```
$orders = auth()->user()->orders()->get();
```

And to get `orders` with `users` as relation use

```
$user = auth()->user()->load('orders');
```

Now you can get `orders` like `$user->orders`

Answer (score 0):

You Should first check query in Tinker which you called ERM is correct or not.
Then Try this code change. you should use get() or all() at then end.

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = auth()->user()->orders->all();
        return view('pagini.my-orders')->with('orders', $orders);

    }
```

Comment: i made a DB::select(DB::raw("select * from orders")) in tinker and it shows me all my orders. When I use $orders = auth()->user()->orders()->all(); it gives me an error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::all() and when I use get(); it gives me the same result, nothing showing up in @foreach

Comment: If in tinker you are getting correct output then at controller page kindly check have call use Model At top. If yes then check in model the function which having Eloquent Relationship with different model has been set proper or not

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked. I am just to focused on errors and I forgot that I was logged in on an account that has no orders.. Sorry for that, thank you all!